# Laravel 5 select and lists relations

Tags: list, select, laravel-5

I have some problems on Laravel 5, I need this query return to lists:

```
SELECT CONCAT(pmt_location.localName,
    IF (LENGTH(pmt_location.dialCode) > 0,
        CONCAT( ' (+', pmt_location.dialCode,')'
        ),
      ''
    )
    ) AS localName,
    pmt_location.id
FROM
    pmt_location
WHERE
    pmt_location.type = 'CO'
ORDER BY
    pmt_location.sOrder ASC,
    pmt_location.localName ASC
```

I am trying like that but it is still not right:

```
$query = DB::select("SELECT CONCAT(pmt_location.localName, IF ( LENGTH(pmt_location.dialCode) > 0, CONCAT(' (+', pmt_location.dialCode, ')'), '' )) AS localName, pmt_location.id FROM pmt_location WHERE pmt_location.type = 'CO' ORDER BY pmt_location.sOrder ASC, pmt_location.localName ASC");

return $query->lists('localName', 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution myself, maybe will help other rookies :P.

```
return DB::table('pmt_location')
    ->select(array("pmt_location.id", DB::raw("CONCAT( pmt_location.localName, IF ( LENGTH(pmt_location.dialCode) > 0, CONCAT(' (+', pmt_location.dialCode, ')'), '' )) AS localName")))
    ->whereRaw("pmt_location.type = 'CO'")
    ->orderBy('sOrder')
    ->orderBy('localName')
    ->lists('localName', 'id');
```